# Fire Button click event during onsubmit

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom-events

I want to fire a click event during the `onsubmit` of form. In button click event I used a url which it has to redirect. I don't want to use the form's 'action" to redirect the page.

Can anyone help me in this?

Answer (score 1):

Add an onsubmit event handler to your form element as follows:

```
form onsubmit='javascript:window.location.href="http://google.com"; return false;'
```